# Reading 39GB CSV filde data in chunk size. I couldn't append the chunks in one df format

Tags: python, pandas, large-data, chunks

1. read as follows

```
c_size=10000000
c_chunk = pd.read_csv("CHARTEVENTS.csv", index_col=0, chunksize=c_size)
```

2. wanted here each chunk in df format

```
c_list= []
for chunk in c_chunk:
    chunk.columns=['ROW_ID', 'SUBJECT_ID', 'HADM_ID', 'ICUSTAY_ID', 'ITEMID', 'VALUE', 'VALUENUM', 'VALUEUOM']
    c_list.append(chunk)
```

3. the plan is to append the chunk to list. however i get an empty list, what do you think happened

```
c_chunk = pd.concat(c_list)
```

4. As a result of empty list, i am getting valueError: no objects to concatenate. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: `chunk_list` vs `c_list` typo?

Comment: sorry that is typo when i was posting the question, not in the main code. Thank you. I will edit.

Comment: Can you post a small (10 rows by 5 columns) sample of your CSV file?  This seems at first glance like it should work...

Comment: I tried your code with my own csv file, and it works fine. Check this question, maybe it helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas

Comment: is your `pd.read_csv()` within the for loop? also are you renaming the columns with the `.columns` argument?